# Unable to resolve the page using value stored in localstorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on angularjs code, where i created a factory method for redirecting the user to profile page once login is successful and updates the flag variable in factory method. The resolve property i attached with the route isn't working as expected, and it seems that "islogged" variable isn't reading the value retrieved from localstorage.

```
  .when('/Login',{
    templateUrl: "/views/login.html",
    controller: "logctrl",
    })

  .when('/Profile',{
        templateUrl: "/views/profile.html",
        resolve: ["authService",function(authService){
            return authService.checkstatus();
        }]
    });
});

app.factory("authService",function($location){
    return {
        "islogged" : localStorage.getItem("islog"),
        checkstatus :function() {
            if(this.islogged)
                return true;
            else
                $location.path(['/Login']);
                return false;
        }

    }
});
```

This is the controller for login :

```
app.controller('logctrl',function($scope,$http, $location){
    localStorage.setItem("islog",false);
    $scope.log = function(){ 
        var uname = $scope.username;
        var pass = $scope.password;
        var logobj = {
            "username" : uname,
            "password" : pass
        };  

        $http.post("http://localhost:3000/sign",logobj).then((resp)=>{
            $location.url(resp.data);
            localStorage.setItem("islog",true);
        }).catch((err)=>$location.url("/"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure if that is the issue, but localstorage in your `authService` factory should be in lower camel case - `localStorage`

Comment: Thats not an issue,, just a typo i made here

Comment: do you still have an issue here?

Comment: Please help with the issue